# You are loading @emotion/react when it is already loaded

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I feel like I've tried everything here, but any help would be great to solve this issue.

I have a component I've published, and i cannot resolve the "You are loading @emotion/react ..." warning message.

```
  // components package.json dependencies:
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": ">=10.x",
    "@emotion/styled": ">=10.x",
    "@hakit/core": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": ">=4.x",
    "react": ">=16.x",
    "react-dom": ">=16.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.x"
  }
```

```
// components vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig(configEnv => {
  return {
    build: {
      lib: {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
        name: 'hakit-components',
        formats: ['es', 'umd'],
        fileName: (format) => `hakit-components.${format}.js`,
      },
      rollupOptions: {
        external:[
          ...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies),
          'react/jsx-runtime',
          'react-is',
          'javascript-time-ago/locale/en.json'
        ],
        output: {
          globals: {
            react: 'React',
            'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
            '@emotion/styled': '@emotion/styled',
            '@emotion/react': '@emotion/react',
            'react/jsx-runtime': 'react/jsx-runtime',
            '@hakit/core': '@hakit/core',
            'lodash': 'lodash'
          }
        }
      },
      minify: true,
    },

    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ['@emotion/react']
    },
    resolve: {
      dedupe: ['@emotion/react'],
      alias: {
        '@emotion/react': '@emotion/react/jsx-runtime'
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      tsconfigPaths({
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, './')
      }),
      react(),
      linterPlugin({
        include: ['./src}/**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
        linters: [new EsLinter({ configEnv })],
      }),
    ],
  }
});
```

Then on my main project, I'm installing the above package to it, as well as `@emotion/react @emotion/styled @emotion/babel-plugin` as dev dependencies.

The vite config of the main project:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({
    jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
    babel: {
      plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
    },
  }),],
})
```

I feel like I've read 20 odd issues of the same problem, all with totally different solutions, I'd just like to know where I've gone wrong, if I'm building it incorrectly on the package side, or using it incorrectly on the project side, any help would be unreal!